# Self-closing ShowDialog box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. When the program is run, Form1 is the form that starts. I then want to call Form2, display it in front of Form1, do some stuff in Form2, and then automatically close Form2 without any input, so the user can continue using Form1.

I have tried the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
        otherForm.ShowDialog();

        //do more stuff here after Form2 has opened and closed
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //do some stuff here

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

When I try this, I get an ObjectDisposedException with the message "Cannot access a disposed object." I've tried searching the internet, but haven't found anything. I've tried using this.Dispose() instead, as well as using .Show() instead of .ShowDialog(). Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible in this manner?

I've thought about making Form2 it's own .exe and calling the .exe as an alternative, but thought I would ask the experts of StackOverflow before rewriting everything.

Comment: What do you want to do on Form2 exactly? Closing it in constructor seems counter-productive.

Comment: whats the `this.Close` for at the end of the form2 constructor? Just take it out. ShowDialog closes the form for you

Comment: @orhtej2 Form2 is a window that will check for updates and give a real time status where it is. I have a mutli-line textbox that is disabled that I am displaying multiple lines of text in. I want to check for updates, if there are updates download the updates, and then close the check for update window.

Comment: @pm100 ShowDialog requires user input to close. I don't want the user to have to manually close the window. I want to close it myself after I'm done checking for updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Markus, because your `Form2` constructor calls `this.Close()`, the Form2 window is already closed once the line `Form2 otherForm = new Form2();` finishes.

The `close()` method releases resources in addition to closing the window (and any owned windows). As a result, in the following line, when `otherForm.ShowDialog();` is called, it cannot access `otherForm` (which was disposed already) and throws the `ObjectDisposedException`. This explains why you are experiencing the exception.

To fix it, remove `this.Close()` from your Form2 constructor. You will still have to call the `close()` method, but do it outside of the constructor and after you have done the things you want to do in Form2.

For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
        otherForm.Show(this);
        otherForm.DoStuff();

        //do more stuff here after Form2 has opened and closed
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // do stuff here as you wish
        // close method goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to change it to .Show() instead of .ShowDialog(), but this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This won't work. Since `.ShowDialog()` is used, `otherForm.DoStuff();` will be called only when the `otherForm` is closed. You should have `otherForm.Show(this);` to have .DoStuff() execute.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call

```
//Do some stuff
this.close()
```

later - not in the constructor - but e.g. in Form.Activated Event.

Sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();

        //Stuff Done
        MessageBox.Show("Stuff Done");
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Activated += DoSomeStuff;
    }

    private async void DoSomeStuff(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Do You Stuff here
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a Form.Load event, but not a Form.Loaded event?

Comment: Sorry: I'm using WPF. If Windows Forms has no Loaded Event you have to use any Event which is fired AFTER the Form is shown. You have to do your stuff also in this Event, at least if you want to show something to the user while doing your stuff...